# python3 - ImportError: No module named '_chipset'

Tags: kernel, python, python3

I tried to run python3 script as follows :

```
$python3 quick_dump.py
```

...but every time I get output as :

> ImportError: No module named '_chipset'

I just watched the **quick_dump.py** script imports and here they are :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# register definition format:
# ('register name', 'register offset', 'register type')
#
# register types:
#  '' - normal register
#  'DPIO' - DPIO register
#
# vim: tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4

import argparse
import os
import sys
import ast
import subprocess
import chipset
import reg_access as reg
```

I tried the $python3 -> help() util to see if chipset module is available; I can see the chipset module presents in the list; So all should be fine but it is not :P *btw I don't see **_chipset** module in the list so maybe this is the thing?*

I watched the chipset.py script and here its code :

```
# This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
# Version 3.0.2
#
# Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
# the SWIG interface file instead.





from sys import version_info
if version_info >= (2,6,0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_chipset', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _chipset
            return _chipset
        if fp is not None:
            try:
                _mod = imp.load_module('_chipset', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _chipset = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _chipset
del version_info
try:
    _swig_property = property
except NameError:
    pass # Python < 2.2 doesn't have 'property'.
def _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self,class_type,name,value,static=1):
    if (name == "thisown"): return self.this.own(value)
    if (name == "this"):
        if type(value).__name__ == 'SwigPyObject':
            self.__dict__[name] = value
            return
    method = class_type.__swig_setmethods__.get(name,None)
    if method: return method(self,value)
    if (not static):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
    else:
        raise AttributeError("You cannot add attributes to %s" % self)

def _swig_setattr(self,class_type,name,value):
    return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self,class_type,name,value,0)

def _swig_getattr(self,class_type,name):
    if (name == "thisown"): return self.this.own()
    method = class_type.__swig_getmethods__.get(name,None)
    if method: return method(self)
    raise AttributeError(name)

def _swig_repr(self):
    try: strthis = "proxy of " + self.this.__repr__()
    except: strthis = ""
    return "<%s.%s; %s >" % (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__, strthis,)

try:
    _object = object
    _newclass = 1
except AttributeError:
    class _object : pass
    _newclass = 0



def is_sandybridge(*args):
  return _chipset.is_sandybridge(*args)
is_sandybridge = _chipset.is_sandybridge

def is_ivybridge(*args):
  return _chipset.is_ivybridge(*args)
is_ivybridge = _chipset.is_ivybridge

def is_valleyview(*args):
  return _chipset.is_valleyview(*args)
is_valleyview = _chipset.is_valleyview

def is_cherryview(*args):
  return _chipset.is_cherryview(*args)
is_cherryview = _chipset.is_cherryview

def is_haswell(*args):
  return _chipset.is_haswell(*args)
is_haswell = _chipset.is_haswell

def is_broadwell(*args):
  return _chipset.is_broadwell(*args)
is_broadwell = _chipset.is_broadwell

def is_skylake(*args):
  return _chipset.is_skylake(*args)
is_skylake = _chipset.is_skylake

def intel_get_pci_device():
  return _chipset.intel_get_pci_device()
intel_get_pci_device = _chipset.intel_get_pci_device

def intel_register_access_init(*args):
  return _chipset.intel_register_access_init(*args)
intel_register_access_init = _chipset.intel_register_access_init

def intel_register_read(*args):
  return _chipset.intel_register_read(*args)
intel_register_read = _chipset.intel_register_read

def intel_register_write(*args):
  return _chipset.intel_register_write(*args)
intel_register_write = _chipset.intel_register_write

def intel_register_access_fini():
  return _chipset.intel_register_access_fini()
intel_register_access_fini = _chipset.intel_register_access_fini

def intel_register_access_needs_fakewake():
  return _chipset.intel_register_access_needs_fakewake()
intel_register_access_needs_fakewake = _chipset.intel_register_access_needs_fakewake

def pcidev_to_devid(*args):
  return _chipset.pcidev_to_devid(*args)
pcidev_to_devid = _chipset.pcidev_to_devid

def intel_dpio_reg_read(*args):
  return _chipset.intel_dpio_reg_read(*args)
intel_dpio_reg_read = _chipset.intel_dpio_reg_read

def intel_flisdsi_reg_read(*args):
  return _chipset.intel_flisdsi_reg_read(*args)
intel_flisdsi_reg_read = _chipset.intel_flisdsi_reg_read
# This file is compatible with both classic and new-style classes.
```

So my question is ... how to fix the error or is there a way of optimal workaround?

---

**EDIT :**

I tried to a) configure b) compile c) install the [intel-gpu-tools](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/) sources with make util; so it seems to be installed now but still I cannot call quick_dump; I input "**$sudo quick_dump**" but I get "*sudo: quick_dump: command not found*" as an output :(

pls give me a tip what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this script and what is it supposed to do? It seems to perform some hardware diagnostics. Is it some kind of programming task?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for your comment;  No, it is not a programming task; You are right the script helps to debug the i915 kernel module http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/quick_dump; The script generates so called "quick dump"; The thing is I have intel-gpu-tools installed but still I cannot run the quick_dump.py script because of the mentioned error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_chipset` is supposed to be a native module (see `chipset.i` in the [same directory](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/quick_dump)), that you need to build from source apparently.

Rough download and compilation instructions:

1. Install `git` with the package manager and clone the repository:

   ```
   git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools
   cd intel-gpu-tools
   ```
2. Install build tools (`build-essential autoconf automake gcc`), prerequisites (see last section of `README`) and run `./autogen.sh` (which tells you about missing prerequisites).
3. Build: `make -C tools/quick_dump`
4. Install: `sudo make -C tools/quick_dump install`

I didn't try it myself, since it would be difficult to install i915 driver development files here.

Comment: You mean I have to download sources and compile? I am a bit confused how to download sources from cgit?

Comment: I am a bit confused you mean cgit.freedesktop.org or "anongit.freedesktop.org" ?

Comment: `cgit` is a web interface for Git repositories, `anongit` is the subdomain for plain anonymous Git access in this instance. They provide access to the same repositories through different protocols.

Comment: OK I'll try all your instructions and tell you my results

Comment: I tried to a) configure b) compile c) install with make util; so it seems to be installed now but still I cannot call quick_dump; I input "$sudo quick_dump" but I get "sudo: quick_dump: command not found" as an output :( pls give me a tip what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ...btw and I tried to compile just the /tools/quick_dump/ directory but I couldn't because of "No ... rule" errors so I had to compile the root app "/" directory :( Is is OK or I have somehow to compile the content of /tools/quick_dump/  separately as well?

Comment: It's normal, that the build system only works from the top directory. For the `command not found issue`, see [Simple file doesn't run (command not found!)](/q/44565/175814).

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I succeeded to run the quick_dump; There was a bug in multi-platform support; So I had  to use newly created patch for intel-gpu-tools to handle the problem; The patch link is "http://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/47175/ " ; So yes you are right concerning config/compile/install steps but for using intel-gpu-tools' quick_dump on Linux Arch OS for example intel-gpu-tools should be patched to be compiled...